# Access Items in Rally Recycle Bin via API

Tags: api, rally

I am trying to access deleted Rally items (in the recycle bin) via the API. I suspect deleted items have a revisions history record saying it has been deleted but haven't found that to be true yet.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I just tested this, but rally.get() only returns things with the Recycled attribute set to False. Using a query to return just one known thing from the Recycle bin does not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an attribute `Recycled` on work items indicating if it's in the recycle bin.

Comment: Thanks Larry for answering my question. I was able to find the objects in the recycle bin.

Comment: It's not clear to me that rally.get() returns anything with the Recycled attribute set.